# Multiple templates for single custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, template-tags

Does anybody know of a way to modify the wordpress template process so that a single custom post type can be displayed on two separate templates based on the value of a custom field.

For example I have a single Custom Post Type called "plans"

It is using the single-plans.php and archive-plans.php files as templates by default.

What I would like to do is use this bit of code to filter out some of the results within my loop.

```
<?php //Filter the results based on the presence of $var
   $var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true);
    if($var !== '') { ?>
      THE LOOP
    <?php } ?>
```

This works fine but i need create two separate templates where I can test for separate $var 
so I can have two menu items that each call on a separate version of the template and get a unique set of results from my single CPT

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be side-stepping your question, but can you use [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)?

```
<?php 

    get_template_part( 'plans', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true ) ); 
?>
```

Then create "plans_plana.php" and "plans_planb.php" (assuming that 'my_custom_field' can have values of 'plana' and 'planb').

twentyten and twentyeleven make heavy use of get_template_part if you need some more examples.

Comment: Great thought Jer I am probably trying to create a function that already exists in wordpress.  I will read up on this and let you know if it solves my problem.

Comment: Just getting back to let you know it is working great. Thanks so much for opening up my mind to another great feature in WordPress.